# How can i save all javascript output in to a txt file for later use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

I'm working on my website (https://factgen.glitch.me/) and I'm trying to get more facts for my generator. I realise i can just make a node.js project and `npm install dog-facts` if i wanted more dog facts but everytime i run it and another fact goes through console I'm hoping there is a way to save it all to a text file in the same directory like `facts.txt`. I'm not sure if this is possible or not so any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

P.S: I'm using https://repl.it to get the facts but https://glitch.com to host my site (glitch has shorter links)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fs` for it

```
const facts = require('covid-facts');
cosnt fs = require('fs');

facts.all.map(item=>{
    fs.appendFileSync('facts.txt', item);
});
```

Comment: I tried this put in the facts.txt i just get "[object Object]"

Comment: could you try `console.log(fact)`. Let see what inside

Comment: ```var facts = require('covid-facts');
console.log(facts)``` is what i was using to get my facts

Comment: [
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined
] is what came out the console and yes, it worked perfect! Where can i add \n to the code or something so i could make them in rows so it ill be easier to put in json
?

Comment: any chance you could upvote the question :)

Comment: `fs.appendFileSync('facts.txt', item+ '\n');`

Comment: Dude, You're awesome! Thanks so much! This is gonna make finding facts so much easier.

Comment: could you hlp me again please

Comment: tried to do                                                                                                          ```const randomfact = require('anime-facts');
const fact = randomfact.facts();

console.log(fact);

const fs = require('fs');

fact.all.map(item=>{
    fs.appendFileSync('facts.txt', item);
});```                                                                                                                
but I'm getting ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined``` @Mike Malyi

Comment: `const fact = randomfact.facts`

Comment: Didnt work but its cool. I already have like 4k facts now and i guess thats good enough,